# Why does db.Model.get_by_id() return None when no parent is specified?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running the following code in the GAE interactive console (/_ah/admin/interactive), and I do not understand why get_by_id() returns None when the parent is not specified.  The docs do not make this limitation clear and I can't think of a reason to enforce it.

```
import my_model
print my_model.all().fetch(1)[0].key().id()  # Returns 33006, used later
print my_model.get_by_id(33006)
print my_model.get_by_id(my_model.all().fetch(1)[0].key().id())

parent = my_model.all().fetch(1)[0].parent()
print my_model.get_by_id(33006, parent=parent)
```

Output:

```
33006
None
None
<my_model object at 0x109a6a690>
```

db.Model definition and code showing object creation with ancestor:

```
class my_model(db.Model):
    user_id = db.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    email = db.StringProperty(indexed=True, default=None)

    def create(parent):
        obj = my_model(user_id='x', email='y', parent=parent)
        obj.put()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is: because the same ID could be in another entity but with a different parent.

The IDs will be all different with the same parent or for all entities without a parent, but if there is an ancestor then your numerical IDs are not unique.